# nested sections in the tableview in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, mvvm, uitableviewsectionheader

```
{
    "data":[
            {
            
            "mainquestion":"was the staff",
            "items":[
            
              {
              "button_type":"2",
              "question": "Gender",
              "options": ["Male","Female"]
            
              },
              {
              "button_type":"2",
              "question": "How old are you",
              "options": ["Under 18","Age 18 to 35","Age 36 to 50","Age 51 to 70","70 and above"]
            
             }
           ]
            }, {
            
            "mainquestion":"Please tell the feedback",
            "items":[
                     
                     {
                     "button_type":"2",
                     "question": "Gender",
                     "options": ["Male","Female"]
                     
                     },
                     {
                     "button_type":"2",
                     "question": "How old are you",
                     "options": ["Under 18","Age 18 to 35","Age 36 to 50","Age 51 to 70","70 and above"]
                     
                     },
                     {
                     "button_type":"2",
                     "question": "How old are you",
                     "options": ["Under 18","Age 18 to 35","Age 36 to 50","Age 51 to 70","70 and above"]
                     
                     }
                     ]
            }
            ]
   }
```

This is my json data.I need to display the data in the tableview as below screen shot.

[This is the screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFiSj.png)I need to display in this way.

```
Currently my code is below.


  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        
        return dummyDataViewModel.numberOfSections()
        print(dummyDataViewModel.numberOfSections())
        
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        
        let identifier = "DummyDataHeaderCell"
        
        
        var headercell: EQ_DummyDataHeader! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? EQ_DummyDataHeader
        
        if headercell == nil {
            
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "EQ_DummyDataHeader", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            
            headercell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? EQ_DummyDataHeader
            
        }
        
        headercell.setReviewData(reviews:self.dummyDataViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection:section))
        
        return headercell
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        
        if tableView == tableview{
            
            return 50
        }
        return 20
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return dummyDataViewModel.numberOfRowsIn(section: section)
        
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let model = dummyDataViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.section)
        print(model.answerType1)
        
        print(model.answerType1?.rawValue)
        
        let c = model.answerType1
        let cellClass = c?.cellType().getClass()
        print(cellClass)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: (cellClass?.cellReuseIdentifier())!, for: indexPath) as! BaseCell
        print(cell)
        
        
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        
        let optionModel = dummyDataViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
        cell.setOptions(Options1: optionModel)
        
        cell.type = c?.cellType()
        
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.textdelegate = self
        cell.textdelegate1 = self
        
        cell.datedelegateDatepicker1 = self
        
        cell.selectDateDelegate = self
        if optionModel.isSelected! {
            cell.setOptions1(OptionsSelected:optionModel)
            cell.TextDisplay(options:optionModel)

            
        } else {
            cell.setOptions1(OptionsisSelected:optionModel)
            cell.setOptions(OptionsisSelected:optionModel)
            cell.setOptions1(OptionsisSelected:optionModel)
            cell.TextNotDisplay(options:optionModel)

        }
        print(cell.type)
        
        if cell.type == .starratingtype{
            
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
        }
        else if cell.type == .smileytype{
            
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
        }
        else if cell.type == .checkboxtype{
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
        }
        else if cell.type == .radiotype{
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
        }
        else if cell.type == .textfieldtype{
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
        }
            
        else if cell.type == .smileytype{
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
        }
        

        return cell
        
        
    }
```

In the view model:-

```
 func numberOfSections() -> Int{
        print((datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!)
        return (datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!
    }
    
    func titleForHeaderInSection(atsection section: Int) -> EQ_DummyDataModel {
        print(datasourceModel.dataListArray![section])
        return datasourceModel.dataListArray![section]
    }
    
    func numberOfRowsIn(section:Int) -> Int {
        
        print( datasourceModel.dataListArray?[section].optionsModelArray.count ?? 0)
        return datasourceModel.dataListArray?[section].optionsModelArray.count ?? 0
        
    }
  
    func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> EQ_OptionModel{
        
        print(datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.section].optionsModelArray[indexPath.row])
        
        return datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.section].optionsModelArray[indexPath.row]
    }
```

I am doing in mvvm .So how to implement the nested section in this code?
What are the changes needed to do in the number of sections and datasource.

Comment: how to implement it?

Comment: How to implement the nested sections in the  tableview?